# Input stirng was not in correct format

Tags: sql, visual-studio, stored-procedures

I'm using Sql2008 and working on visual studio 10, i trying to updating data using passing parameters with some condition and Whnever i compile my that code i got the error like

> "Input string was not in a correct format."

Error at this line

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@User_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value =Convert.ToString("Select User_ID from User_Master where User_Name='t11'")
```

Comment: please suggest me what to do

Comment: You are passing Query as value. The Value must be Integer. Can you post some of the code in the same function?

Comment: what exactlyyou want to do

Answer (score 0):

```
"Select User_ID from User_Master where User_Name='t11'";
```

First your run this query and returned value store in one variable. Then using this variable to passing value.

like variable should be id.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@User_ID", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["@User_ID"].Value = id ;
```

Comment: There is no @ User_ID parameter in the query. The User_Name value is hardcoded. Also @ User_ID and @ ID are different parameters.

Answer (score 0):

**SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("tester_changePassword_sp_2", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

id = "Select Max(User_ID) from User_Master_View";

cmd.Parameters.Add("@User_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(txt_confirm_password.Text);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();**

Comment: i have used id as a string..but @Mukesh sir still it giving same error